# zend application returning not found for images/css/js

Tags: zend-framework

My zend app running onlocal zend server 6 is returning not found for all images,css and javascript files.

My .htaccess in public contains:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l 
   RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

routes.ini contains

```
    [production]
    routes.default.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
    routes.default.route = "dev.localhost.com"
    routes.default.defaults.module = "default"
    routes.default.defaults.media = "media"

    ;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ; Default Route - Default Behaviour 
    ;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    routes.default.chains.index.route = ":controller/:action/*"
    routes.default.chains.index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
    routes.default.chains.index.defaults.controller = "index"
    routes.default.chains.index.defaults.action = "index"
```

And I call as

```
    <img src="<?= $this->baseUrl('images/logo.png'); ?>"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo$this->baseUrl('css/grid.css')?>"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('css/styles.css')?>" />
    <?php $this->headScript()->prependFile($this->baseUrl('js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.js'));
```

?>

All of which return a not found error, wiht base url set to either '/'
 or 'http://dev.localhost.com'

Any help much appreciated

Comment: 1st of all check the source code and make sure the generated URLs for those assets are correct.

Comment: Cheers it turned out it was zend server, I presumed it set everything up nicely, as it turns out it sets everything up nicely for it's useless default structure, should have stuck with xampp.